# JetBrains Rider not catching ArgumentOutOfRange exception from Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, exception, rider

Is it just me ? Also Rider is very slow.
Tried with an empty Unity project with just a script and an empty list:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class TestException : MonoBehaviour
{

private List<int> emptyList= new List<int>();

void Start ()
{

    emptyList[11] = 0;
}
}
```

JBR 2018.2.3
Unity 2018.2.8f1

Comment: I got `ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Argument is out of range.` JBR 2018.1.3, Unity 2018.2.0x improved prefabs

Comment: General recommendations on speeding up Rider https://rider-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/360000797440
Otherwise, specify, what is exactly slow.